# Why does loading small images eat CPU time?

Tags: cpu-usage, animation

I noticed that (on my Ubuntu, and also on other Linux distributions, e.g., Debian) small animated images eat CPU time. When I open multiple Firefox tabs, the CPU raises to 100% and it's because of then small loading images in top of each tab.

There are so many examples of this effect (high CPU usages for loading images). When connecting to a wireless network (i.e., wireless icon is animated), and animated gifs (ajax loadings) in web pages, etc.

Can I solve and prevent this problem? (e.g., like with an OS graphic configuration option)

Answer (score 1):

The CPU load is very likely not because of Firefox animating something in its tab bar but *because it's busy loading and rendering a page you requested*.

Comment: No, what about connecting to wireless (with animating icon), or even viewing a simple gif in image viewer? or a simple loading gif in a web page?